# XPATH - how to get the text if an element contains a certain class

Tags: xpath

```
<a href="#faq-default-2" class="">JHow do I grab this text here?</a>
```

I am trying to grab the text here based on that the href contains "#faq-default".

I tried this first of all but it doesn't grab the text, only the actual href name, which is pointless:

```
//a/@href[contains(., '#faq-default-2')]
```

There will be many of these hrefs, such as default-2, default-3 so I need to do some kind of contains query, I'd guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting the `@href` node value instead of the `a` element value. So try this instead:

```
//a[contains(@href, '#faq-default-2')]
```